# Нахождение координат вершин правильного n-угольника

Tags: геометрия, координаты

Вообщем. Заданы такие параметры:

1. целое число — размер стороны квадрата в пикселях;
2. вещественное число k — коэффициент масштабирования (<1);
3. целое число n — количество повторений.

Если k = 0.8 и n = 20, то получится вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно находить координаты вершин для каждого квадрата

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по примеру, `k` - не совсем коэффициент масштабирования, в таком случае решается так:

Задаем вершины начального квадрата

> A<sub>0</sub> = (0, 0)
>   B<sub>0</sub> = (w, 0)
>   C<sub>0</sub> = (w, w)
>   D<sub>0</sub> = (0, w)

На каждом шаге рассчитываем новые вершины

> A<sub>n</sub> = k·A<sub>n-1</sub> + (1 - k)·B<sub>n-1</sub>
>   B<sub>n</sub> = k·B<sub>n-1</sub> + (1 - k)·C<sub>n-1</sub>
>   C<sub>n</sub> = k·C<sub>n-1</sub> + (1 - k)·D<sub>n-1</sub>
>   D<sub>n</sub> = k·D<sub>n-1</sub> + (1 - k)·A<sub>n-1</sub>

Для вашего примера

> A<sub>0</sub> = (0, 0)
>   B<sub>0</sub> = (250, 0)
>   C<sub>0</sub> = (250, 250)
>   D<sub>0</sub> = (0, 250)
>
> A<sub>1</sub> = 0.8·(0, 0) + 0.2·(250, 0) = (50, 0)
>   B<sub>1</sub> = 0.8·(250, 0) + 0.2·(250, 250) = (250, 50)
>   C<sub>1</sub> = 0.8·(250, 250) + 0.2·(0, 250) = (200, 250)
>   D<sub>1</sub> = 0.8·(0, 250) + 0.2·(0, 0) = (0, 200)
>   ...

[Пример реализации](https://code.world/haskell#Pw6TYGBpnSC-T2sUOL7TWxg)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообще, для квадрата достаточно будет хранить две любых вершины из предыдущей итерации, чтобы рассчитать все остальные.